# Erlang decode binary data from packet

Tags: erlang, udp, decode, packet

I get an UDP packet, like so:

```
<<83,65,77,80,188,64,171,138,30,120,105,0,0,0,10,0,4,0,0,0,84,101,115,116,15,0,0,0,82,101,122,111,110,101,32,82,111,108,101,80,108,97,121,11,0,0,0,83,97,110,32,65,110,100,114,101,97,115>>
```

How can I decode packet if I know that I can remove first 11 bytes, and the 12-13 byte contains amount of players online on the server (Byte width is 2), how can I get this amount?

**UPD**
Maybe I send incorrect packet...
[SAMP Query](http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Query_Mechanism)
So, I send:

```
<<$S,$A,$M,$P,188,64,172,136,7808:16,$i>>
```

For server 188.64.172.136:7808, and I get

```
<<83,65,77,80,188,64,172,136,30,128,105,0,0,0,10,0,4,0,0,0,84,101,115,116,15,0,0,0,82,101,122,111,110,101,32,82,111,108,101,80,108,97,121,11,0,0,0,83,97,110,32,65,110,100,114,101,97,115>>
```

Comment: We may have a counting problem here. Which are the 2 bytes which you want to return? How many players are there in this case? Can you give a (simple) spec of the packet structure? Or a reference?

Comment: sure, here is [backbone of packets](http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Query_Mechanism#The_backbone_of_packets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [bit syntax](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#bit_syntax) and clever pattern matching to get the result:

```
<<_:11/bytes, NumberOfPlayers:16/integer-big, _/binary>> = <<83,65,77,80,188,64,171,138,30,120,105,0,0,0,10,0,4,0,0,0,84,101,115,116,15,0,0,0,82,101,122,111,110,101,32,82,111,108,101,80,108,97,121,11,0,0,0,83,97,110,32,65,110,100,114,101,97,115>>,
NumberOfPlayers.
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I get 0, and real online is 29 :) Here is the query mechanism of SAMP: [link](http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Query_Mechanism#Recieving_the_packets)

Comment: Well, you said the bytes 12-13 contain the amount of players online. When I count them in your packet, I see zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

If your packet binary is stored in `P`, you can do something like (assuming big endian):

```
<<NumberOfPlayersOnline:16/big>> = binary:part(P,11,2).
```

The result is in `NumberOfPlayers`.

Comment: Well, in the binary you shown above, characters 12 and 13 are `<<0,0>>`, so this is expected :)

Comment: Be sure then that what you're receiving is not an error/diagnosis message that actually is not answering your query. In other words: When you get a real answer, obtaining the value of bytes 12 and 13 will use the code shown above (or the one given by Artefact2).

Comment: Search on the spec where an error flag is stored, then check for it using a similar syntax to obtain the correct byte out of the binary.